# How to update user details according to this model and controller in Node.js express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to update user data in the settings page. Where he/she can change all details like name, last name, birthday and so on. Here is the auth controller:

```
module.exports = {
      async CreateUser(req, res) {
        const schema = Joi.object().keys({
          username: Joi.string()
            .min(4)
            .max(10)
            .required(),
          email: Joi.string()
            .email()
            .required(),
         firstName: Joi.string()
            .required(),
          lastName: Joi.string()
            .required(),
           position: Joi.string()
            .required(),
          password: Joi.string()
            .min(5)
            .required(),
        });

        const { error, value } = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);
        if (error && error.details) {
          return res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({ msg: error.details })
        }

        const userEmail = await User.findOne({
          email: Helpers.lowerCase(req.body.email)
        });
        if (userEmail) {
          return res
            .status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
            .json({ message: 'Email already exist' });
        }

        const userName = await User.findOne({
          username: Helpers.firstUpper(req.body.username)
        });
        if (userName) {
          return res
            .status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
            .json({ message: 'Username already exist' });
        }

        return bcrypt.hash(value.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) {
            return res
              .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
              .json({ message: 'Error hashing password' });
          }

          const age = moment().diff(moment([value.byear, value.bmonth - 1, value.bday]), 'years');
          const body = {
            username: Helpers.firstUpper(value.username),
            email: Helpers.lowerCase(value.email),
            firstName: value.firstName,
            lastName: value.lastName,
            position: value.position,
            password: hash,
          };
          User.create(body)
            .then(user => {
              const token = jwt.sign({ data: user }, dbConfig.secret, {
                expiresIn: '5h'
              });
              res.cookie('auth', token);
              res
                .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                .json({ message: 'User created successfully', user, token });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res
                    .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .json({ message: 'Error occured' });
            });
          });
        },
```

**User model**

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String },
  email: { type: String },
  isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  firstName: { type: String },
  lastName: { type: String },
  position: { type: String },
  password: { type: String },
```

I guess I shoud have a route like this:

```
router.post('/user/settings', AuthHelper.VerifyToken, user.editUser);
```

How should it look like editUser controller according to above CreateUser function? I am using Angular in the front-end. But I think it doesn't matter.  I assume 90 percent should be the same as CreateUser but what exactly should be changed so the user can update his/her details in settings form and change data in the model?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to update some of user's fields (such as firstName, lastName and etc.), not replacing the whole information. Then you might want to get the current user's data first and then update only those allowed fields.

Please find the sample code below.

```
/**
 * User router
 */
router.put('/user/:userId', AuthHelper.VerifyToken, user.editUser);

// This function will be triggered when Express finds matching route parameter
router.param('userId', function (req, res, next, id) {
    User.findOne(id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        } else if (user) {
            // When it finds user information, bind that to request object, which will be used in the other middlewares.
            req.user = user;
            next();
        } else {
            next(new Error('failed to load user'));
        }
    });
});

/**
 * User controller
 */
exports.editUser = (req, res, next) => {
    let { user } = req;

    // You pick only allowed fields from submitted body
    const allowedFields = { firstName: req.body.firstName, lastName: req.body.lastName, birthday: req.body.birthday };

    // Override the current user data with new one
    user = Object.assign(user, allowedFields);

    user.save((err, savedUser) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.json(savedUser.toJSON());
    });
};
```

Comment: So where should I implement app.param function?

Comment: I haven't mentioned that there are actually two choices, one is using `param()` in application level and the other one is using `param()` in the router level. I think in your use case, you can simply use `router.param()`, so answer is Add 'router.param()' in your route js file.